# Defining parameters for executing stored procedure - Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic, jscript

I am trying to update some old functionality. There is a stored procedure that has one input parameter and two output parameters. I am getting the following error when I try to execute the code:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e21'

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

/student.asp, line 30
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Api].[GetKeyByAuthId]
    @AuthenticationId uniqueidentifier
,   @Key int = NULL OUTPUT
,   @type varchar(25) = NULL OUTPUT
```

Direct call works great:

```
USE [Development]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @Key int,
        @type varchar(25)

EXEC    @return_value = [Api].[GetKeyByAuthId]
        @AuthenticationId = '0550F579-DBDA-4C41-82B3-453841A6232E',
        @Key = @Key OUTPUT,
        @type = @type OUTPUT

SELECT  @Key as N'@Key',
        @type as N'@type'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Authentication Id is unique identifier and is received via query string on the page. Here is my code, line 30 is cmd.Execute:

```js
var cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
cmd.CommandText = "Api.GetKeyByAuthId";
cmd.CommandType = 4;   // Stored procedure


var p = cmd.Parameters;
p.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@AuthenticationId", 72, 1));
p.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Key", 3, 2, 9));
p.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@type", 200, 2, 25));

cmd("@AuthenticationId") = aid;

cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn;
cmd.Execute();

Key = cmd.Parameters("@Key");
type = cmd.Parameters("@type");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing your data types in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746442/defining-parameters-for-executing-stored-procedure-classic-asp/23746811?noredirect=1#comment36583687_23746811)

You mentioned that the Stored Procedure expects `@Key` as an `Int` but the underlying table data type for the field is `BigInt`.

> **Warning**
>
> The problem with this approach is that the conversion from `BigInt` to `Int` is dangerous (see [SQL - safely downcast BIGINT to INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097171/sql-safely-downcast-bigint-to-int)). Most of the time you will get
>
> ```
> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
> ```
>
> You can suppress the exception using a combination of
>
> ```sql
> SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF -- Divide-by-zero and arithmetic overflow errors cause null values to be returned
> SET ARITHABORT OFF    -- Don't terminate the query on Divide-by-zero and arithmetic overflow errors
> SET ARITHIGNORE ON    -- Suppress errors from Divide-by-zero and arithmetic overflow errors
> ```

My guess is the

```
Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors
```

error in your Stored Procedure is being caused by an `Arithetic overflow error` because the value you are retrieving in `@Key` is too big to fit in an `Int` data type.

When possible I would speak to your developers and explain the situation and see whether the Stored Procedure can be modified to pass `@Key` as `BigInt`.

Answer (score 0):

These two changes worked for me at this time:

```
p.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@AuthenticationId", 200, 1, 37));

var KeyDb = cmd.CreateParameter("@Key", 131, 2);
KeyDb.NumericScale = 0;
KeyDb.Precision = 9;
p.Append(KeyDb);
```

Comment: Interesting so you're using `adNumeric`, is your `@Key` parameter defined as `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` and not `INT` in the stored procedure `[Api].[Getkeybyauthid]`? I'm guessing so explains why your direct call works because SQL will automatically handle the conversion from `INT` to `NUMERIC` for you whereas `ADODB.Command` will expect the exact data type.

Comment: @Key is bigint in the table.

Comment: In that case you should be using `adBigInt` (20), but it's not the table data type but the stored procedure parameter data type that is important.

Comment: I am bit confused now... sproc has this as int and i don't have any control over it. Db team refused to change it (and i understand) as the same sproc may be used by other apps as well. Even though it is int in the sproc, do i still need to set it up as adBigInt (20) at my end?

Comment: That is a strange one. You shouldn't have to because the Stored Procedures definition for `@Key` is an `INTEGER`. That is really dangerous though because your `@Key` field could contain a value larger then `INTEGER` in which case you might get strange behaviour when the Stored Procedure returns the `BIGINT` as an `INTEGER`. See [SQL - safely downcast BIGINT to INT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097171/sql-safely-downcast-bigint-to-int).

Comment: @Lankymart please put your above comment as an answer so that i can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just execute it like this?

```
var1 = ""
var1 = var1 & "USE [Development]"
var1 = var1 & " " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "go"
var1 = var1 & " " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "DECLARE @return_value INT, " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "        @Key          INT, " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "        @type         VARCHAR(25)"
var1 = var1 & " " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "EXEC @return_value = [Api].[Getkeybyauthid] " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "  @AuthenticationId = '0550F579-DBDA-4C41-82B3-453841A6232E', " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "  @Key = @Key output, " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "  @type = @type output"
var1 = var1 & " " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "SELECT @Key  AS N'@Key', " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "       @type AS N'@type'"
var1 = var1 & " " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value"
var1 = var1 & " " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "go "
cmd.execute(var1)
```

Comment: No. This will not give me the return values to use inside the app.

Comment: @learning... Actually it will (if you set-up the parameters correctly and assign `OUTPUT` where required), but I wouldn't do it this way anyway.