# Can select float value but fail to insert it

Tags: sql-server

When I select I get the following value: `1.79769313486232E+308`

The Column type is float.

When I'm trying to insert this value to the same table and column, I'm getting the following error:

> The floating point value '1.79769313486232E+308' is out of the range of computer representation (8 byte)

When I select with `master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(ColumnName)` I'm getting
the hex value as `0x7fefffffffffffff` which is less then 8 bytes...

Any explanation please?

Comment: Probably  rounding - expotential representation has limited digits. `SELECT max_float = (1 + (POWER(2e0, 52) - 1) / POWER(2e0, 52)) * POWER(2e0, 1023)` [DB<>FIDDLE demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=950e1888c7930783f5590ab81872943f)

Comment: [Getting maximum value of float in SQL programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38020122/5070879)

Comment: the hex value is `0x7fefffffffffffff` which is less then 8 bytes...

Comment: I made program to copy/backup several tables using SQL script, I can get the value but I fail to restore it.